# xml special characters on scrapy

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy

I have this html

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest">&lt;</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/cars/?sort=newest&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest&amp;page=4">4</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest&amp;page=5">5</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/cars/?sort=newest&amp;page=3">></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to take the `href` of the `a` tag in the last `li`

I tried this:

```
.//div[@class='pagination']/ul/li[last()]/a[normalize-space(.)='>']/@href
```

**on scrapy shell** and it works perfectly.

#### My problem

I am reading that xpath from xml file so I can't use the `'>'` in the xml because `>` is a special charaector. So, i replace that `>` with `&gt;`,
but then when I tested the result on scrapy shell, I got empty result.

I also tried `&gt;` but still getting empty results

help please

Comment: Why not just use `//div[@class='pagination']/ul/li[last()]/a/@href` ?

Comment: Two questions: How does your XML look like, exactly? How are you reading the XPath from the XML? Show the code that does that.